# Shopify - When do orders_count & total_spent fields of Customer object show real value?

Tags: api, e-commerce, shopify

I want to know when the orders_count & total_spent fields of Customer object show real values. When I fetch my orders I mostly get values as 0, 0.0 for orders_count & total_spent fields respectively, for orders placed by new customers, even though the orders are not cancelled.
When I try to fetch this values again later by fetching the Customer object I do get correct values.

Do you update the values after some intervals in batches? OR Do they show up correctly after some particular Order status.
What is the way to correct this?

Kindly let me know as its breaking the logic that is based on these values.

Comment: I request the Shopify engineers to address my query, I suppose this is the only place to get in touch with them. I see some queries posted after this being answered. Kindly let me know if anything is not clear in my post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Orders and customers are created independently and associated with one another in the background. This means there will be a delay between orders being created in these values being updated. Your best bet is to listen for order/updated webhooks and when the customer is present in the webhook the values should all be set.

Comment: Hi John, I have Orders with value say some $50 or more that were paid for 2 days ago. And now that I fetch the Order, Customer I still get the orders_count as 0 & total_spent = 0.00.
I understand the delay that you mentioned but it definitely cannot be 48hrs. What are the cases when such(0) values are returned for Orders? When would reflect the real values say 1, $50 respectively for the example I mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

One thing worth mentioning that is not covered in the Shopify documentation, is that using a Bogus Gateway as payment will cause those orders to not be counted correctly by `{{ customer.orders_count }}` in the checkout Extra Scripts area. I got in touch with one of their engineers and they suggested using Cash on Delivery to check, lo and behold `{{ customer.orders_count }}` started to return correct values.

Settings > Payments > Manual payment methods > COD